# HMErrorDomain Code=45 - The operation couldn’t be completed - syntax issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, type-conversion, homekit

**Assumption:** I am Using Xcode 6.3.1

Reading the HomeKit documentation I see the following:

```
 [characteristic writeValue:@2 completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
 }];
```

- What is the data type of @2?
- How can I pass a value (e.g. NSString, NSNumber) to the writeValue function?

---

**EDIT:** When I tried

```
 [characteristic writeValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] completionHandler:^(NSError *error)
```

It gives me an error.

> Error Domain=HMErrorDomain Code=45 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (HMErrorDomain error 45.)"

If I try @2 it works.

**Why?**

Comment: Ah ah, but how can you get that value format?

Comment: The `[NSNumber numberWithInt: 42]` part should work. If it doesn't, then please give the exact error message.

Comment: FWIW, in older versions of Xcode, @42 might not work. I don't remember when this syntax was introduced, but it was not too long ago.

Comment: I am using Xcode 6.3.1

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: it's been around for quite some time already

Comment: No Mac nearby right now. I guess it is a problem with your characteristic class.

Comment: FYI, "HMErrorDomain error 45" is AKA "HMErrorCodeValueHigherThanMaximum"

Comment: @rdurand: Well yes, but what is "quite some time"? I can still remember that it was introduced, so it can't have been too long ago. <g>

Comment: Yes, was giving the wrong value ... sorry!

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: I'm pretty sure it was before HomeKit, so he can't be on an old version of Xcode :)

Comment: Just looked. It was early 2012. Heck, it looked like a lot less time ago to me. I'm getting old. <g>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an [NSNumber literal](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html), equivalent to `[NSNumber numberWithInt:42]`.

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't make sense to me. Those should be exactly equivalent.

Comment: I was giving the wrong value... sorry! Thanks for the answer which helped clarify